# node text not shown (circuitikz)

Tags: circuitikz, tikz-node

I'd like to increase the space around a node to be able to show the text content. In the example below, I want the text "Channel 1" to be visible above node `oscopeshape`. I've tried nodifiying the node attributes with `outer sep` without success.

Thanks in advance for your help !

[image: text of node oscopeshape hidden]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt,convert={density=600,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx,RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[american]
\draw(0,0) to[sV,l=$v(t)$] ++(0,3) to[R,l=$R$] ++(4,0) to[C,l=$C$] ++(0,-3) --(0,0);
\ctikzset{bipoles/oscope/width=1.4}
\ctikzset{bipoles/oscope/height=1.0}
\node[oscopeshape, fill=green!10, anchor=south, outer sep=20pt](O1) at (4,4) {$\text{Channel 1}$};
\node[bnc, xscale=-1, anchor=zero](bnc11) at (O1.in 1) {};
\node[bnc, anchor=zero, rotate=-90](bnc12) at (O1.in 2){};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The text is already there, it just can't be seen. Try with `\documentclass[convert={density=600,outext=.png},margin=2cm]{standalone}`

Comment: I deleted my answer, since the comment above naturally solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. @Ivan, indeed, that solves my original question (the text is visible now)

Comment: Thanks @Rmano, indeed the increasing the margins adds additional space all around the circuit, which was not originally intended

Comment: For the sake of completeness, would it be possible to add space 'locally' around the node of interest (i.e, to increase the vertical space only in one direction, or any other solution) ? Was something alone these lines what @SebGlav was proposing ?

Comment: The @SebGlav proposal was to add the text as an extra node, like `\node[above =2pt of O1] {Channel 1};` --- that will take into account the size automatically

Comment: As a rationale for the behavior, in `circuitikz` the geographical anchors do not change when the node text is outside the component (it's evident in transistors too). This is a design decision, to enable the alignement of  components independently from the labels. Normally works ok, sometimes it bites you like in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `border={2pt 2pt 2pt 12pt}`:

```
\documentclass[border={2pt 2pt 2pt 12pt},convert={density=600,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx,RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
 
 \begin{circuitikz}[american]
  \draw(0,0) to[sV,l=$v(t)$] ++(0,3) to[R,l=$R$] ++(4,0) to[C,l=$C$] ++(0,-3) --(0,0);
  \ctikzset{bipoles/oscope/width=1.4}
  \ctikzset{bipoles/oscope/height=1.0}
  \node[oscopeshape, fill=green!10, anchor=south, outer sep=20pt](O1) at (4,4) {$\text{Channel 1}$};
  \node[bnc, xscale=-1, anchor=zero](bnc11) at (O1.in 1) {};
  \node[bnc, anchor=zero, rotate=-90](bnc12) at (O1.in 2){};
 \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @SebGlav Could you please undelete your solution?

Comment: I did but I doubt it's relevant since the problem here was clearly related to the border/margins.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** As per request, I undeleted my solution, which is kind of a cheat, but with which you don't have to take care of the margins.

Does something like that suit you?

```
\documentclass[border=2pt,convert={density=600,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx,RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american]
        \draw(0,0) to[sV,l=$v(t)$] ++(0,3) to[R,l=$R$] ++(4,0) to[C,l=$C$] ++(0,-3) --(0,0);
        \ctikzset{bipoles/oscope/width=1.4}
        \ctikzset{bipoles/oscope/height=1.0}
        \node[oscopeshape, fill=green!10](O1) at (4,4) {};
        \node[above =2pt of O1] {Channel 1};
        \node[bnc, xscale=-1, anchor=zero](bnc11) at (O1.in 1) {};
        \node[bnc, anchor=zero, rotate=-90](bnc12) at (O1.in 2){};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: oscilo]

Comment: I don't think it's a cheat: it is what I would use in this case, short of adding a fake "path" instruction. The problem is that the margin are miscalculated because the `circuitikz` text for the scope node is invisible to Ti*k*Z bounding box calculation routine; your solution makes it "visible". +1