# Label of an element is out of frame

Tags: circuitikz, standalone

I want to draw a Darlington assembly with two transistors. For the layout: no problem!

On the other hand, the label of the 2nd transistor is outside the frame by taking as the standalone document class (which I prefer to keep to facilitate the export of the image later).

I know that an inelegant solution is to artificially increase the margins but I am thinking that maybe there is a "cleaner" solution?

Thanks for your response

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[european, straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) node[pnp](T1){T1};
\draw (T1.emitter) node[pnp, anchor=base](T2){T2};
\draw (T2.collector) |- (T1.collector);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In `circuitikz ` node text down not contribute to the alignment nor bounding box. This is the same as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586283/node-text-not-shown-circuitikz - notice my comment here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586283/node-text-not-shown-circuitikz#comment1473545_586283. You can use @Zarko method or just all an invisible path to T2 `\path (T2.east) ++(2em,0)` or something similar. In bigger circuit is not a problem normally.

Comment: Sorry for the &ß@ing autocorrect of the message above: *down: do not, *all: add, *circuit: circuits (well, last one is me, but...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why this happens will be probably explained by (one of) the package authors. Meanwhile you can use the following workaround:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[european, straightvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw   (0,0) node[pnp, label=right: T1] (T1) {} 
        (T1.emitter) node[pnp, anchor=base, label=right: T2] (T2) {}    % <---
        (T2.collector) |- (T1.collector);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]